# Failing to start up default rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to start up a default rails server by following command,

```
rails _5.2.1_ new hellworld
cd helloworld
bundle install
rails s
```

and it gives me the error below. Is there anything I need to do before starting a server?

```
[WARNING] Could not load command "rails/commands/server/server_command". Error: uninitialized constant URI::Generic.
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI
```

Versions
Ruby 2.5.0 installed with rbenv version 1.1.2

Comment: after `cd helloworld` did you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: yes, I initially didn't run `bundle install`, but I have tried that as well.

Comment: Seems to be related to Ruby 2.5.0. I came here because my Travis CI showed a similar warning. It is gone on Ruby 2.5.7 though.